# How to add new record to database with AngularJS and Laravel 5 on right way

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs, laravel-5

I found a guide on how to write AngularJS the right way: https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide#factories

In Laravel, I created my POST route `/api/addnew` and now I need to pass params from Angular to Laravel.

This is my form:

```
<form id="1" class="dd animated slideInDown ng-pristine ng-valid">
    <textarea class="form-control" placeholder="Vas Komentar" id="rep_text_0"></textarea>
   <a href="javascript: void(0);" add-comment class="btn btn-default pull-right">Send</a>
</form>
```

And my factory:

```
angular.module('commentsApp')
.factory('commentFactory', dataService);

dataSerive.$inject();

function dataService() {
    var someValue = '';
    var service = {
        save: save,
        someValue: someValue
    };
    return service;

    ////////////

    function save() {
        /* */
    };
}
```

Click directive:

```
angular
    .module('commentsApp')
    .directive('addComment', addNewComment);

function addNewComment() {
    var directive = {
        link: link,
        restrict: 'A'
    };
    return directive;
    function link(scope, element, attrs) {
      /* */
    }
}
```

I'm stuck on how to pass details from the form to Angular and then make a post request on /api/addnew with the params?

Is there any way to use the click directive on a button to send params to the factory?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think is necessary a directive for a click...
instead use ng-click and manage data (model) from the controller.

```
<div ng-controller="yourController">
    <form id="1" class="dd animated slideInDown ng-pristine ng-valid">
        <textarea class="form-control" placeholder="Vas Komentar" id="rep_text_0" ng-model="yourCommentModel"></textarea>
       <a href="#" class="btn btn-default pull-right" ng-click="sendText(yourCommentModel)">Send</a>
    </form>
</div>
```

In your controller you can use $http or your own factory.

```
yourApp.controller('yourController', function($scope, $http, yourFactory){
    $scope.sendText = function(data){
      //http code...
      //or yourFactory code..
    };
});
```